# how to get username from login form, when reset password link is clicked django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the username from my login form when the reset password link has been pressed.

view.py

def ResetPassword(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.Post.get['login_username']
    if username:
        #send password reset link via email 
    else:
        #if username is empty search for your account 
        return render(request, 'accounts/forms/email_search.html',{})
```

forms.html

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar" method="POST"action="{% url 'login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">
           {{ form.login_username }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ form.login_password }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <br>
       <a href="{% url 'ResetPassword' %}">Reset Password</a>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the request object has not attribute `Post`, but [`POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

So, it should be either

```
# use this if you're sure that login_username will always be passed 
`username = request.POST['login_username']`
```

or

```
# use this and in case login_username fails, then an empty string is returned
`username = request.POST.get('login_username', '')`.
```

Now, to your problem. The form has a submit input only for the `login` view. The `change password` button is just a plain link. Thus, when you click on it you make a `GET` request to the `ResetPassword` view (by the way, you should rename it to `reset_password`, it's the Python way), without any arguments passed.

To fix this, you must remove this link from inside the form. 
Then you have to create the template for the `ResetPassword` view, say `reset_password.html` and inside there create another form (with only the `username` field required) that will `POST` to `ResetPassword` view.

For example:

```
<!-- reset_password.html -->

<form class="navbar-form navbar" method="POST" action="{% url 'ResetPassword' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login_username" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="reset-pwd-btn" class="btn btn-default">Reset Password</button>
</form>
```

And last:

```
# ResetPassword.py    

def ResetPassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # login_username is the same as the input's name
        username = request.POST.get('login_username')
        if username:
            # send password reset link via email
        else:
            # if username is empty search for your account
        return render(request, 'accounts/forms/email_search.html', {})
    return render(request, 'accounts/forms/reset_password.html', {})
```

Comment: if I use the first option I get this error MultiValueDictKeyErro, if I use the second option it returns none

Comment: Updated my answer. There are several modifications you have to do it order to work, although! But easy though!